# Airflow 2.4.0 ghost dag runs showing up in UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

After updating my Airflow setup from 2.3.3 to 2.4.0, ghost dag_runs appeared on some of my dags. These dag_runs have seemingly random schedule dates from past and they can't be found from the db using the details view search and Run ID. What are they and how do I get rid of them. Running my usual db cleanup dag does nothing to these an otherwise dags keep on running normally.
[image]

Comment: This fixed the issue:
`airflow db clean --clean-before-timestamp '2022-09-01 00:00:00+01:00'`